# Generating Swagger docs in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an application that I'm building an API into. It's a .net 4.6 MVC app.  I'm building the API into a controller, but for some reason swagger won't see my controllers.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[TokenFilter]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestApiController : Controller
{
    #region GENERAL DATA
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTestCompany()
    {
```

This is how i have my controller laid out.  I just a a blank screen that has the UI and says

```
[ base url: , api version: v1 ]
```

Nothing else is on the page.

I'm using Swashbuckle

Comment: have you configured swagger at `GlobalConfiguration` in webapi.config.cs?

Comment: This is a .net mvc project. not a web api project.

Answer (score 2):

Swagger doesn't work with mvc controller unfortunately. It only works with ApiController for a Restful API